# Items showing up in app bar of design view but not in emulator of Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeHGq.png)
I am a beginner learning android development. I am trying on the app bar. But I faced a problem.
Some items are showing up in design view but not showing up in the emulator of Android Studio.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.tutorials

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.example.tutorials.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.tutorials.databinding.ActivitySecondBinding

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.app_bar_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.miAddContact -> Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Add Contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.miFavourites -> Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.miSettings -> Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.miFeedback -> Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked on Feedback", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.miClose -> finish()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**app_bar_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miSettings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miAddContact"
        android:title="Add Contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_contact"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miFavourites"
        android:title="Favourites"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favourites"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miFeedback"
        android:title="Give Feedback"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/miClose"
        android:title="Close App"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Can someone help me out. Thank you!

I tried changing emulator size. I made sure I inflate the correct menu. But still not working.

Comment: try `android:showAsAction="always"` instead of `app:showAsAction="always"`.